# Memories in virtual machines(VMware) are ECC memories？

Tags: memory, virtual-machines

I think the memories in virtual machines(VMware) are simulative ECC memories, am I right?
so I use memspeedc tool test a virtual machines(VMware) and a linux server machine with real ECC memory, comparing with a non-ECC PC memory.

-------------------------------------------------------------/

virtual machine memory test result:

-------------------------------------------------------------/

Reading and writing 32 bits at a time.

Testilg L1 Cache ( 32 KiB):

Sequential read:               1247 MiB/s       3.059 ns

Sequential write:              1642 MiB/s       2.323 ns

Random read:                    982 MiB/s       3.883 ns

Random write:                  1015 MiB/s       3.760 ns

Interdependant random read:     629 MiB/s       6.065 ns

Testilg L2 Cache (256 KiB):

Sequential read:               1313 MiB/s       2.904 ns

Sequential write:              1649 MiB/s       2.314 ns

Random read:                    791 MiB/s       4.821 ns

Random write:                   628 MiB/s       6.079 ns

Interdependant random read:     365 MiB/s      10.458 ns

Testing L3 Cache   (4 MiB):

Sequential read:               1160 MiB/s       3.289 ns

Sequential write:              1362 MiB/s       2.801 ns

Random read:                    109 MiB/s      35.026 ns

Random write:                   162 MiB/s      23.493 ns

Interdependant random read:      52 MiB/s      73.360 ns

Testing memory   (256 MiB):
Sequential read:               1213 MiB/s       3.144 ns
Sequential write:              1141 MiB/s       3.344 ns
Random read:                     61 MiB/s      62.138 ns
Random write:                    81 MiB/s      47.386 ns
Interdependant random read:      27 MiB/s     140.518 ns

-------------------------------------------------------------/

real ECC memory test result:

-------------------------------------------------------------/

Reading and writing 32 bits at a time.

Testilg L1 Cache ( 32 KiB):

Sequential read:               1106 MiB/s       3.450 ns

Sequential write:              1094 MiB/s       3.487 ns

Random read:                    829 MiB/s       4.599 ns

Random write:                   953 MiB/s       4.005 ns

Interdependant random read:     531 MiB/s       7.181 ns

Testilg L2 Cache (256 KiB):

Sequential read:               1106 MiB/s       3.449 ns

Sequential write:              1086 MiB/s       3.511 ns

Random read:                    692 MiB/s       5.511 ns

Random write:                   447 MiB/s       8.529 ns

Interdependant random read:     349 MiB/s      10.923 ns

Testing L3 Cache   (4 MiB):

Sequential read:               1106 MiB/s       3.449 ns

Sequential write:              1082 MiB/s       3.526 ns

Random read:                    442 MiB/s       8.631 ns

Random write:                   183 MiB/s      20.836 ns

Interdependant random read:     139 MiB/s      27.384 ns

Testing memory   (256 MiB):

Sequential read:               1082 MiB/s       3.527 ns

Sequential write:               966 MiB/s       3.949 ns

Random read:                     98 MiB/s      39.041 ns

Random write:                    37 MiB/s     103.116 ns

Interdependant random read:      29 MiB/s     130.683 ns

-------------------------------------------------------------/

non-ECC memory test result:

-------------------------------------------------------------/

Reading and writing 32 bits at a time.

Testilg L1 Cache ( 32 KiB):

Sequential read:               6382 MiB/s       0.598 ns

Sequential write:             11907 MiB/s       0.320 ns

Random read:                   3071 MiB/s       1.242 ns

Random write:                  3336 MiB/s       1.143 ns

Interdependant random read:    1261 MiB/s       3.024 ns

Testilg L2 Cache (256 KiB):

Sequential read:               5897 MiB/s       0.647 ns

Sequential write:              9303 MiB/s       0.410 ns

Random read:                   1583 MiB/s       2.409 ns

Random write:                   799 MiB/s       4.777 ns

Interdependant random read:     412 MiB/s       9.259 ns

Testing L3 Cache   (4 MiB):

Sequential read:               3788 MiB/s       1.007 ns

Sequential write:              1816 MiB/s       2.101 ns

Random read:                    302 MiB/s      12.631 ns

Random write:                   228 MiB/s      16.727 ns

Interdependant random read:      46 MiB/s      83.384 ns

Testing memory   (256 MiB):

Sequential read:               3346 MiB/s       1.140 ns

Sequential write:              1741 MiB/s       2.190 ns

Random read:                     79 MiB/s      48.280 ns

Random write:                    86 MiB/s      44.242 ns

Interdependant random read:      28 MiB/s     137.046 ns

Comment: Simulating ecc on non-ecc memory would have **HUGE** overhead and slow everything to a crawl.

Answer (score 2):

No, you're wrong, no hypervisor would dream of simulating ECC behaviours to its guests - how would that work anyway?

Anyway, no, that doesn't happen - terribly-worded question by the way.